# c programming array element subtraction

Tags: c, algorithm

```
array a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8];
array a2 = [1, 4, 5];
array a3 = a1 - a2; /* [2, 3, 8] */
array a4 = a2 - a1; /* print -None */
```

Here array would be the type my program uses to represent a struct which is used as a container. The rest of it is pseudo code, of course I'm not creating the arrays like that nor subtracting.

The simplest solution I can think of involves nested loops. any idea to solve an efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: I am not using python for this algorithm. I am using c programming. #Arc676

Comment: @Arc676, what language are you referring to, or what struct containing pointers to functions?

Comment: In the case of numerical values in a limited range as in the example, it can be represented by bits.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Whoops, sorry. Was on some Python questions earlier Python lists are delimited by brackets.

Comment: Gotcha, that really had me scratching my head...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon. As it stands, your question is too broad to be a good fit on SO. Please read about how yo create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You should show some real code and ask about the problems you're having with it.

Answer (score 1):

You want set difference.  If both arrays are sorted, and contain no duplicates, you can iterate through both simultaneously:in linear time.

Whenever you encounter an element b in list B greater than the current element a of A, you can be sure that B does not contain a (or it would not be sorted).  Then a is in A and not B, so it is in your output.  Proceed to the next element of A, and compare it to the first element of B greater than the previous a, which is your current b.  If b < a, it is also less than any remaining element of a, so you can advance to the next element of b.  If you do encounter a == b, it is not in the set difference, so compare the next elements of both lists. If you reach the end of B first, add all remaining elements of A.  When you reach the end of A, stop.

You can sort a list and remove duplicates in O(n log n) time, or faster if you can radix sort.

---

### Sample Code

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_set( const size_t asize, const int a[asize] )
{
    const ptrdiff_t n = (ptrdiff_t)asize;
    assert(n >= 0);

    putchar('{');
    if (n > 0) {
        printf( "%d", a[0] );

        for ( ptrdiff_t i = 1; i < n; ++i )
            printf( ", %d", a[i] );
    }
    putchar('}');
    fflush(stdout);
    return;
}

size_t setdiff( const size_t asize, const int a[asize],
                const size_t bsize, const int b[bsize],
                const size_t csize, int c[csize] )
/* Calculates c = a - b, where a, b and c are sets.  Returns the number of
 * elements in c.  The destination array c must be large enough to hold the
 * result (asize elements are always enough).  All sets must be sorted and
 * contain no duplicates (checked at runtime).
 */
{
    ptrdiff_t i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    const ptrdiff_t m = (ptrdiff_t)asize;
    const ptrdiff_t n = (ptrdiff_t)bsize;
    const ptrdiff_t p = (ptrdiff_t)csize;

    assert(m >= 0);
    assert(n >= 0);
    assert(p >= 0);

    while ( i < m ) {
        if ( j == n || a[i] < b[j] ) {
            assert( k < p );
            c[k++] = a[i++];
            assert( i == m || a[i] > a[i-1]);
        } else if ( a[i] > b[j] ) {
            ++j;
            assert( j == n || b[j] > b[j-1]);    
        } else {
            assert( a[i] == b[j] );
            ++i;
            assert( i == m || a[i] > a[i-1]);
            ++j;
            assert( j == n || b[j] > b[j-1]);
        }
    }

    return (size_t)k;
}

int main(void)
{
    static const int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    static const size_t m = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    static const int b[] = {1, 4, 5};
    static const size_t n = sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]);
    int c[6] = {0};
    static const size_t p = sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]);

    print_set( m, a );
    printf(" - ");
    print_set( n, b );
    printf(" = ");
    const size_t q = setdiff( m, a, n, b, p, c );
    print_set( q, c );
    printf(".\n");

    print_set( n, b );
    printf(" - ");
    print_set( m, a );
    printf(" = ");
    const size_t r = setdiff( n, b, m, a, p, c );
    print_set( r, c );
    printf(".\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the two arrays are sorted, as in your examples, you should be able to locate common elements optimally using `bsearch`. I've provided an example, but in the future **please make an effort to write your own C code in the future**, then I/we might be able to help you better!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int compare(void const *x, void const *y) {
    return memcmp(x, y, sizeof (int)); // XXX: This might not be what you expect for negative values!
}

size_t difference(void *dest, size_t dest_size, void const *x, size_t x_size, void const *y, size_t y_size, size_t size, int (*compare)(void const *, void const *)) {
    typedef unsigned char item[size];
    item const *a = x, *b = y;
    item *d = dest;
    size_t cursor = 0, d_size = 0;
    for (size_t x = 0; x < x_size; x++) {
        item *ptr = bsearch(a + x, b + cursor, y_size - cursor, size, compare);
        if (ptr) {
            cursor = ptr - b;
        }
        else {
            memcpy(d[d_size++], a[x], sizeof (item));
        }
    }
    return d_size;
}

void print(char *name, int array[], size_t array_size) {
    printf("%s: %s", name, array_size ? "" : "NONE\n");
    for (size_t x = 0; x < array_size; x++, putchar(x < array_size ? ',' : '\n')) {
        printf("%d", array[x]);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8 },
        b[] = { 1, 4, 5 },
        c[sizeof a / sizeof *a],
        d[sizeof a / sizeof *a];

    size_t c_size = difference(c, sizeof c / sizeof *c,
                               a, sizeof a / sizeof *a,
                               b, sizeof b / sizeof *b,
                                  sizeof (int), compare);
    size_t d_size = difference(d, sizeof d / sizeof *d,
                               b, sizeof b / sizeof *b,
                               a, sizeof a / sizeof *a,
                                  sizeof (int), compare);

    print("c", c, c_size);
    print("d", d, d_size);
}
```

Comment: You say OP should put in some more effort themselves in future, but why would they do that if people just write code for them either way?

Comment: @Dukeling Presumably for mental exercise/practice, self gratification, or some sense of worth... or many other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will obviously need a find function:

```
int find(int val, const int* a, int na)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < na; ++i)
  {
     if (val == a[i])
       return i;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

The diff function become quite trivial, assuming you have an allocated array for the result. r should be able to hold at least na elements.

```
int diff(int* r, const int* a, int na, const int* b, int nb)
{
  // returns the number of elenment in resulting set.
  // on output r contains the elements from a that are not found in b
  // expects r to provide enough room for na elements
  int i, nr;
  nr = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < na; ++i)
  {
     if (find(a[i], b, nb) < 0)
     {
        r[nr++] = a[i];
     }
  }
  return nr;
}
```

I know that in a sense, this is still a nested loop.  But it is much more readable.  Plus, you've gained a generic find() function that you can use elsewhere in your code.

I thought the difference of two sets was not as you describe, but defined as A with intersection of A and B removed. i.e.  If a value is found several times in A, but only once in B, only one element of A is removed from the result set.  For this case, you'd need a remove function.

```
int remove(int at, int* a, int na)
{
  // removes first occurence of val in a.
  // returns the number of elements in a after remove op.
  if (0 <= at && at < na)
  {
     memmove(&a[at], &a[at + 1], sizeof(int) * (na - (at + 1)));
     return na - 1;
  }
  return na;
}
```

The diff when elements are not unique is not much more complex, we'll loop on b.

```
int difference(int* r, const int* a, int na, const int* b, int nb)
{
   // returns elements from a, minus set b.
   // handles non-unique cases, so this is the true difference or a-b
   // returns the number of elements in resulting set
   int nr, found;

   memcpy(r, a, na * sizeof(int));

   nr = na;
   for (i = 0; i < nb; ++i)
   {
      found = find(b[i], r, nr);
      if (found >= 0)
      {
        nr = remove(found, r, nr);
      }
   }
   return nr;
}
```

I did not try to compile these, so there might be some typos, but it should be fairly close..

Edit: These algorithms have a complexity of O(N^2), so by sorting a (or b) and using a binary search, you could get them down to 1) O(2NlogN) 2) O(3NlogN), which is not bad, since you'd only need to change the find() function to implement optimization.

Comment: This could be a good use case for the `restrict` type qualifier! ([Details](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/05/demystifying-the-restrict-keyword.html))

Comment: That's some contract!  :D